# random number generator returning "0" in Java

Tags: java

I have tested the random number generator and it works fine outside of the app. It's a fairly standard piece of code. I created getters and setters, and NetBeans does not complain about anything being passed to the application, but what should be a random number is a "0". I would like to understand more about getters and setters and classes. I may have designated something incorrectly.

//This is the class code

```
public class RandomGen {

    int minSeed = 100;
    int maxSeed = 999;
    int num;

    public static void RandomNum(int minSeed, int maxSeed) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(maxSeed - minSeed) + 1;
    }

    public void setMin(int minSeed) {
        this.minSeed = minSeed;
    }

    public void setMax(int maxSeed) {
        this.maxSeed = maxSeed;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}
```

This is the code within main in my application

```
RandomGen rnumber = new RandomGen();
int rnum = rnumber.getNum();
int bigSeed = rnumber.maxSeed;
int smallSeed = rnumber.minSeed;

System.out.println("Random Number =  " + rnum);
System.out.println("MaxSeed = " + bigSeed);
System.out.println("MinSeed = " + smallSeed);
```

This is the printed return

```
Random Number =  0
MaxSeed = 999
MinSeed = 100
```

Comment: youre redeclaring num in the constructor, just use num not int num

Comment: Your code `num` variable is not initialized

Comment: Depending on your IDE, there should be a way to turn on warnings for variable hiding.  I suggest you do so; it'll save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: As an aside, you should probably just directly return the random number instead of storing it in a variable and having another method that does nothing but return it.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 1):

You have created a local variable so use the global as

```
num = rand.nextInt(maxSeed - minSeed) + 1;
```

As per your code , you need to call that `static` method to initialize `num` as well so

```
RandomGen rnumber = new RandomGen();
RandomGen.RandomNum(rnumber.minSeed, rnumber.maxSeed);
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
int rnum = rnumber.getNum();
int bigSeed = rnumber.maxSeed;
int smallSeed = rnumber.minSeed;
```

Note: constructors cannot be `static`, can't have any return type

---

```
static int num; // global to class, different from the `num` inside RandomNum

public static void RandomNum(int minSeed, int maxSeed)
 {
    Random rand = new Random();
    // local variable
    // changes here, can only be seen inside RandomNum method
    //int num = rand.nextInt(maxSeed - minSeed) + 1;
    num = rand.nextInt(maxSeed - minSeed) + 1;

 }
```

Comment: Thank you all. Made the changes and learned something, but it still is a zero.  maio290 - you said " you're never calling RandomNum. I tried it , but it breaks immediately.     The other changes were all on target , but I am still getting a zero.  is there another way to expose the random number just so I can see that it is working?

Comment: @HEQX did you change this `num = rand.nextInt(maxSeed - minSeed) + 1;` and call `RandomGen.RandomNum(rnumber.minSeed, rnumber.maxSeed);`

Comment: @HEQX got it, change `int num` to `static int num`, you cannot use non-static variables inside static context though i strongly recommend you to create a parameterized constructor to use non-static members

Comment: Thank you Pavneet and all others. It works now. I never would have seen it that way. So now I have to stare at it for a while. I am writing a complex game and this is a very small part of it, but critical just the same.

Comment: @HEQX i am glad that i could help, happy gaming

Answer (score 0):

first

```
static int num; // must also be static
```

second

```
public static void RandomNum(int minSeed, int maxSeed)
 {
    Random rand = new Random();
    num = rand.nextInt(maxSeed - minSeed) + 1; // remove the declaration you try to make it local variable 

 }
```

Answer (score -2):

This is incorrect.

Try this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomGen {

    private Random random;
    private int minRange;
    private int maxRange;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int minRange = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 100;
        int maxRange = (args.length > 1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[1]) : 200;
        int numValues = (args.length > 2) ? Integer.parseInt(args[2]) : 10;
        RandomGen randomGen = new RandomGen(minRange, maxRange);
        for (int i = 0; i < numValues; ++i) {
            System.out.println(randomGen.getNextIntInRange());
        }
    }

    public RandomGen(int minRange, int maxRange) {
        this(minRange, maxRange, null);
    }

    public RandomGen(int minRange, int maxRange, Long seed) {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.random = (seed == null) ? new Random() : new Random(seed);
    }

    public int getNextIntInRange() {
        return this.minRange + this.random.nextInt(this.maxRange-this.minRange)+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not see it done this way. Why do you say that what I have is wrong?  i did notice that my lower range is not being honored in every case. I am getting numbers below 100 after a few tries. I have not seen anything lower than 50 though. But of course that is incorrect, Will your solution fix this issue?

Comment: Because you create a new Random instance every time you call getNum.   It's a variable that's local to the method.  It needs to be a class method.  If you voted it down, you don't understand how Random works.  Run it and see.

Comment: Ok , I will give it a try. Thank You. I may not know how it works entirely, but I was under the impression that it uses a seed that is based on the number of milliseconds since 1,1 1970. Outside of that I do not know exactly what it is doing internally.

Comment: @HEQX mine runs. Try it.

Comment: Thanks duffymo. Ran great and actually did not fail to maintain the imposed limits. I do not know why the other code did not work within two limits. It seemed pretty standard. Did you want to say anything about Random that you think I need to know?

Comment: If it worked and helped you I'd appreciate if you'd reverse the injustice of the down votes and accept my answer.  You should learn how any Java class works before you use it.  The key is that you should have one Random that you call repeatedly, not one as a private data member.  Lots of people make that mistake; don't be one of them.  You should also fully understand the difference between using a seed and not using one.

Comment: Ok cool, yeah I see that as part of DRY. I have been using Random only once and just applying various parameters to it to get whatever is needed in that part of the program. Thanks for the help. I don't remember downvoting anything. I don't know how to do that anyway.